# Cant open a port on my linux server

Tags: linux, redhat, smtp, port, exim

Here is the thing, my server fails to connect to gmail SMTP with timeout error. I think the 465 port is closed on my server so I did couple of thing, now my `csf.config` file hase this two lines:

```
TCP_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995,2011,2222,8080"
TCP_OUT = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,113,443,2011,2222,8080,465"
```

and I searched the iptable file for `465` and there is three occurance like so:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
```

when I run `netstat -tulpn` command I get this result:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 158.58.184.42:53            0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1938/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1938/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1552/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1681/exim
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9671/httpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1505/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1505/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1689/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1681/exim
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1505/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1505/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9671/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::21                       :::*                        LISTEN      1817/proftpd
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1552/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::25                       :::*                        LISTEN      1681/exim
tcp        0      0 :::587                      :::*                        LISTEN      1681/exim
tcp        0      0 :::2222                     :::*                        LISTEN      1675/directadmin
udp        0      0 158.58.184.42:53            0.0.0.0:*                               1938/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                               1938/named
```

The server ip is : 158.58.184.42 and smtps port (465) is not open yet! What should I do?

Comment: Is your server trying to connect (send) to gmail? Or is it the other way around? Your question doesn't make sense that way it's currently written.

Comment: @MDMarra ~ I am trying to send emails through gmail SMTP. I wrote the code in PHP. but the `fsockopen` function gives error `unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)`

Comment: Your outgoing connections have nothing to do with your incoming firewall!

Comment: @MichaelHampton ~ Sorry but I am newbie in this and I cant follow you! can you please add some details about what I am doing (thinking) wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your firewall is not the problem here, something in your code must be (and thus, this is not the right site to ask on).

What you're doing is allowing *incoming* connections to *your* server on port 465 though your server's firewall. The problem is that when you go to connect to gmail, you're connecting to port 465 on **their** servers. Port 465 on your server has nothing to do with this. There is nothing in that activity that establishes an inbound connection on port 465 on *your* server.

You're barking up the wrong tree, opening these ports isn't going to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I've checked the code, I am pretty sure it is ok. Is there any chance that another upper level firewall is blocking the outgoing trafic on port 465? I am on a VPS, surely the main server got a firewal. Should I check with the Hosting provider (main server administrator)?

Comment: Sure there's a possibility, but it's not probably. I am unaware of any large hosts that filter outbound traffic. You can always ask your host, though.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the output of your "netstat -tulpn" , you have RHEL distros, Exim smtp and Apache web server so you should check /var/log/messages file for more information about your problem with tailf -f command. If you are trying to send mail through PHP you should also check your httpd log file(/var/log/httpd/error_log or for vhosts check your httpd.conf file to find path under the VirtualHost scope)

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
>     DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
>     ServerName dummy-host.example.com
>     **ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log**
>     CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

1. As explained above posts it is not about incoming firewall rules. The problem may be in your outgoing firewall/iptables. Is this complete of iptables-save command output? 
   Try

   iptables -L OUTPUT 
    or
   iptables-save | grep OUTPUT
2. Check your network interface and /etc/resolv.conf file.Your server may not resolve smtp.google.com. Try to ping smtp.google.com or other tools.
3. Check your exim configuration and logs for more details. /var/log/exim_mainlog